# wxWidgets: wxWebView::CanCopy - Prevent User from Copying Need Example

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Setting up webview SetPage Code

```
wxWebView *webView;
webView = wxWebView::New(this, wxID_ANY);
webView->SetPage("****Demo Code******","");
webView->SetEditable(false);
webView->EnableContextMenu(false);
```

**Problem Statement** - Only allow user ability to copy Demo Code if he is subscribed . Looking for override of CanCopy function or any other way to stop copying ( looking for solution for all platforms ).

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_web_view.html#ac7f906e08b4000ee668bc678df0f7dfe

**Returns true if the current selection can be copied.
Note
This always returns true on the OSX WebKit backend.**

Is it possible to **override wxWebView::CanCopy** to prevent copying from all OS ( Windows , Linux, OSX )?

Need sample code.

Comment: if you can find a way to do that for OSX - great. The original author of the control couldn't.

Comment: is it possible on windows?

Comment: the official documentation mentions OSX only. Do you have a proof its not possible on Win? What backend do you use?

Comment: @Igor  im new to wxwebview. What i understand is that i need to overwrite CanCopy in order to return false. I just don't know how to do it.. I cal live with windows working copy as well.. If you can give an working example. that would be of great help

Comment: you understood wrong. The `CanCopy()` function is not overridable. And even if it was - NSWebView doesn't support this. What are trying to do? Can you explain it in a plain terms?

Comment: @Igor - i use wxWebView to display some content generated using backend. I don't want user to copy them without the subscription. So want to write a method which can prevent copy based on some if / else condition

Comment: if you need it under OSX - you are out of luck.Plain and simple. You can try asking on the Apple developer forum, but I think that it just not properly supported for the newer Cocoa interface/new OSX version.

Comment: If you do find a way - please post to wx-users ML.You can also try to do something like here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/6480

Comment: @Igor - i'm looking solution for wxWebView not WKWebView.

Comment: WKWebView is the control behind wxWebView on OSX. It is OSX native control for rendering web content. Just like IE/Edge is on Windows.

Comment: got it!. thanks for the explanation

Comment: You can try handling copy and paste event but users can however still copy text though the DOM tree that can be accessed using the Dev Tools. IMO, you cannot prevent users from copying text in a webpage!